# Selecting children from TreeView using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

The issue that I have is related to `the GetItem()` method from `pywinauto`. I was able to run the `window.TreeView.GetItem('\\Desktop').Click()` command on Windows 7 and 10 both 32 bit but it throws an exeption and does not run when calling it from the python command line of Windows 10 64 bit.

**This is my full code I use:**

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()

w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Browse For Folder', class_name='#32770')[0]

window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)

window.TreeView.GetItem('\\Desktop').Click()
```

**These are the errors that I receive:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1374, in GetItem
    texts = [r.Text() for r in roots]

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 872, in Text
    return self._readitem()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1263, in _readitem
    raise ctypes.WinError()

WindowsError: [Error 0] The operation completed successfully.
```

[Folder Dialog content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2obUO.jpg)

I have to mention that I can only access the root of the tree view by `window.TreeView.GetItem([0]).Click()`

Comment: Do you use 64-bit Python with 32-bit app?

Comment: Yes, Python is on 64bits and the application is on 32bits. Thanks

Comment: You can try UIA branch of pywinauto or use 32-bit Python with pywinauto 0.5.4.

Comment: Thank you sir. For now, I think I'll stick to running the commands in Windows 10 32 bit on which it is working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because Win32 API structure sizes for Windows messages are different for 32-bit and 64-bit apps. It's fixed in UIA branch (you can wait for 0.6.0 planned this summer).

Another way is just to set up 32-bit Python (and pywinauto) in addition to your 64-bit Python (you just need to care about full path to `python.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

Try This one ...

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application
import pywinauto
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(best_match='File Explorer')
dlg = app.File_Explorer

dlg = dlg.ItemsView.get_item('Documents')
dlg.click_input(double = True)
```

Comment: Why does this solution work on both 32 and 64 bit machines?

Comment: You can seen the pywinauto documentation [link] (https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/atspi/pywinauto/__init__.py) the desktop module automatically register the backed